# Pressing ENTER in title submits question/edit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editor

Is this intended behavior? For someone like me with low(er) rep, if this happens while I'm making an edit that I haven't finished yet, I have to push another suggested edit to fix the potentially incomplete formatting or wording.

Could this cause confusion in the review queues since the first edit appears incomplete, or are the edits squashed together?

I'm on Google Chrome. Haven't tested other browsers.

BTW, I posted this by ENTERing the title. (And edited it the same way.)

Comment: Shouldn't this go on meta Stack Exchange, not meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: Unless the question form consisted of a [single text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370021/why-does-forms-with-single-input-field-submit-upon-pressing-enter-key-in-input) I don't think that this should be happening. Inspecting the title field using FF there are 14 events bound to it, so there may be JavaScript to blame.

Comment: @roryap Hmm, good point. This probably affects all SE sites. Is it possible to move it there?

Comment: Please resist the urge to categorize in a way that loses the target audience. (dont move the question to places where the submitter and others affected may not have access to it as they do here)

Comment: I feel like I'm back to mid-90s now.

Comment: @j08691: that should absolutely be happening. See the [living HTML standard on implicit submission](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission). The 'single field' rule was only present in early HTML standards, and only as a recommendation, and that rule is [gone in the HTML 3 standard](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html), and that came out in 1996, 20 years ago.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is [standard behavior for HTML forms](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#implicit-submission):

> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text field is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a form whose default button has a defined activation behaviour must cause the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on that default button.

We could *suppress* this behavior, or avoid it entirely by getting rid of the submit button... But this has potential accessibility concerns, and without a very good reason to avoid it I would think we should prefer to be consistent here with other HTML forms.

If you submit a second edit before the first one is approved, they'll be combined and shown to reviewers (and everyone else if approved) as a single edit.

Comment: Ah, accessibility makes a lot of sense. Accepted!

Comment: Does the list of reviewers get reset when the author of the suggested edit list submits the second edit?

Comment: No it does not, @Ferrybig.

Comment: "_f you submit a second edit before the first one is approved_" <- before it is approved or within the next 5 minutes (grace period)?

Comment: Are you sure it's possible for people <2K to edit questions a second time before the first edit is approved? I seem to recall you get a message telling you to wait.

Comment: Try it, @mrlister

Comment: @MrLister I can confirm the behaviour, and I think it's possibly in-place to allow the editor to change their edit if they missed something/accidentally removed/changed something.

Comment: @cybermonkey Yes; I found a question worth editing on a site where I have low rep, so I can now confirm I can edit a question twice in a row without waiting for approval. Either I was remembering wrong, or this was not so in the past.